# scrapy does not get to the request handler on error

Tags: http, error-handling, scrapy

Yes, I've read that I can inspect repsonse.status to get error code, but the problem is that control does not get to my handler in case of e.g. HTTP Error 400: scrapy reports to the log but gives me no chance to handle the request in my way. In the examle below the next request is done from 'parse' and error is replied to this second request which is handled by 'flight_search_start'.

```
    def parse(self, response):         
       return scrapy.Request(
       ...
            callback=self.flight_search_start,

            )        

    def flight_search_start(self, response):
        session = ...
        if (self.checkError(response, session)):
            return

    def checkError(self, response, session):
        if response.status == 200 or 
response.status == 201 or     response.status == 202:
            return False
NEVER GET HERE!!!
        print "Request failed!!! ",errorData(session)
        return True
```

There is a second problem: when I switch off my router the framework hangs for a long time and does not report any error.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy comes with a mechanism to handle bad response statuses, you just need to pass the `errback` parameter to the Request object.

about you switching off your router, wouldn't that be because you lose internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

By default scrapy ingores codes outside of the 200-300 range. If you want to handle them you have to tell scrapy to let them through, either through the spider, or through settings.py using `HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES` e.g.

```
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [404,403,406, 408, 500, 503, 504]
```

See the documentation [here](http://goo.gl/90XjiV).